# How to view the data from SSAS CUBE

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, ssas-2008

I am new to SQL Server CUBES.

I have processed the CUBE in SQL Server 2008 environment.

How to view the data based on its dimensions?

Do the CUBE needs to be mapped to the Reports to view the data?

Whether the CUBE has to be processed on daily basis to get fresh data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to view a cube is with excel. In excel you can connect to SSAS as long as you have the appropriate permissions. After you connect you should see all of the dimensions. See the article below for more information on excel and SSAS.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-data-from-Analysis-Services-ba86270b-5cc2-4bb9-a21d-8bafc20f0cd3

To view new data a cube must be processed.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216366%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Does the cube needs to processed in order to get fresh data ??